# How to prevent requests from being blocked while a user is uploading an image

Tags: node.js, performance, event-loop

I have an API in node js that receives images. The problem is that I noticed that whenever I start to send an image to the api, other requests from other users are blocked until the image is completely received by the api. How can I resolve this and prevent other requests from being blocked or queued?

Comment: Which version of node.js are you using?

Comment: @rya im using 16.13.2

Comment: Since node.js v12 it is possible to create a worker thread: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads. Maybe putting this upload api on a worker thread will help.

Comment: @rya its possible put an endpoint in a worker? Cause I think the problem is in the time it takes for the api to receive the image from the front end. I do a fetch and this fetch takes 5 - 10 seconds to complete.

Comment: Another solution is to use a load balancer. There are many types of load balancers available out there. For example nginx : https://medium.com/techintoo/load-balancing-node-js-51b854fb4f4f

Comment: @rya This and clustering is the same? Im using heroku, is possível do the same?